# Street view inside infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, maps

I need information from the window of my map contains the google street view and place for text. Can anyone help me solve? I'm learning to program and is difficult to solve alone. Thanks (my code below)

```
function initialize() {
var pinkParksStyles = [
    {
      featureType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -80 }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: "poi.park",
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#ff0023" },
        { saturation: 40 }
      ]
    }
  ];

var pinkMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(pinkParksStyles,
    {name: "Paul em Floripa"});
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.619279,-48.527896),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,'pink_parks','satellite' ]
    }
  };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),  mapOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({})
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var locations = [
                   ['Estacionamento 1', -27.627525,-48.52762, 1],
                   ['Estacionamento 2', -27.624374,-48.527786, 2],
                   ['Estacionamento 3', -27.620154,-48.529138, 3],
                   ['Estacionamento 4', -27.616161,-48.529588, 4],
                   ['Estacionamento 5', -27.61393,-48.533349, 5],
                   ['Estacionamento 6', -27.613129,-48.535352, 6],
                   ['Estacionamento 7', -27.612637,-48.530493, 7],
                   ['Estacionamento 8', -27.616962,-48.527746, 8],
                   ];


var marker, i;
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: 'images/stopcar.png',
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
   })(marker, i));
}

map.mapTypes.set('pink_parks', pinkMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('pink_parks');
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: what information exactly do you try to pull out?

Comment: when I click on the icon the window of google maps. I would like to put the streetview and a space for text. like this

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_SECbW4uPgAM/TNPry0hit6I/AAAAAAAAACc/Wv00oU4TeIQ/s1600/Picture+1.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess you want to put in the info window a static picture of the streetview.
If that is the case please look at this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/

There is exactly written down how to get the static picture of the streetview for a special location.

Comment: If you come to problems while following the documentation, just leave a comment and we can work it out.